# How to update Material Slide toggle value of Parent componemt based on Cancel And Yes button from Dialog Component?

Tags: angular-material, modal-dialog, parent-child, slidetoggle, two-way-binding

I have one "**Manager**"  slide-toggle in **Employee** Component which will be intially **ON** (if managerFlag='Y' ) or **OFF** (if managerFlag='N' ) based on **managerFlag** value coming from database ,
for this i have used **checked** variable and checking condition in **ngOnInit()** and placed this `[checked]="checked"` in HTML Manager toggle button.

When I click on **Manager** toggle, I'll get Dialog of **Manager** Component which have two methods **YES** and **CANCEL**. If I click on **CANCEL** button, toggle should retain its original state.

When I click on YES button, toggle value should update from **OFF** to **ON** and vice-versa to provide/revoke manager access of that Employee.

find below snapshot of EmployeeForm.
Intial Form.
[image]

on Click of Manager Toggle.
[image]

Please Find the code in below URL.
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lqqhah?file=src%2Fapp%2Femployee%2Femployee.component.ts)

Could anyone assist me on this? 
Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/10919587/robert-nish@https://stackoverflow.com/users/2361308/hearen@https://stackoverflow.com/users/1800337/kushan-randima

Answer (score 0):

All you need to know is describe here in the official documentation of Angular Material https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview.

You should create a component for you dialog and add it in the entryComponents of your app-module. Saying you are naming it ConfirmDialog then, in the component where you want to open the dialog

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmDialog);
```

In your ConfirmDialog template, set the directive mat-dialog-close to send back result when user click on YES (true) or CANCEL (false) :

```
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true" >YES</button>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="false" cdkFocusInitial>CANCEL</button>
</div>
```

In the afterClosed method subscription, you will so have either true or false value as argument of your callback and you should set state of your switch button

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  console.log('The dialog was closed');
  // The result should be true or false
  // Affect this value to the checked state of your switch button
});
```

Comment: It's working but Update button is not submitting data on 1st click.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand because can't see Update button on your screen shot. Could you update your stackblitz with your actual code so I could help you ?